Saying "thank you" is not NAA anymore?
I raised an NAA flag on this answer Answer to: Blank space appearing at bottom of all webpages in Google Chrome on iOS [closed] which got declined. As I explained in my comment underneath the post, the "answer" is simply thanking the OP for their workaround/solution. The objectively bad edit has made it harder to spot that fact. Let's look at the original post before the edit:

THANK YOU! Disabling smooth scrolling took care of this problem on my iPhone 14 Pro on iOS 17.2.1.

Now, compare that to this part of the question:*

After much trial and error I discovered that if I disable Chrome's Smooth Scrolling this issue is resolved and all pages behave normally. Solution: Load chrome://flags and set Smooth Scrolling to disable.

I believe my flag was merely declined due to an oversight, but please let me know if I am missing something.
 * Note that the question has never been edited and that part is not added based on the NAA. Again, that "pseudo-answer" is simply thanking the OP for their workaround.

Some people just seem to love getting into involved debates of how should a particular turd be classified and how to correctly dispose of it, instead of, you know, just getting rid of it. Meanwhile dozens more are deposited around them... Someone spends ten seconds mashing the keyboard, and then bunch of other people take few man-hours figuring out what to do with it.

Me, I'd just burn a downvote and a delete vote and not bother involving a mod on a post like that. They have more than enough  to dig through. If other users didn't follow my lead and finish nuking it, maybe I'd poke a mod in a few days, but odds are I'll have forgotten about it by then.

@Ðаո I think, in this case, the regular user tools are decent, though guidance is lacking. Not and never have been a mod, so can't speak on the mod tools. There is a lot of room for improvement in the review queues, and if the mod tools are anything like the review queues... Zoinks.

You are the latest victim of a problem Stack Overflow has had for years; there are conflicting rules about how NAA and VLQ flags are supposed to work.
The NAA flag description says:

This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

(emphasis mine).
This matches the answer you flagged. It is clear, in context, that the answer is not an attempt to answer the question; rather, it is thanking the question asker for some useful information that we can see was contained in the question itself, without providing or attempting to provide any additional information - let alone an answer. If we treat this guidance as definitive, then you were pretty unambiguously correct to raise the flag.
The Help Center links to some network-wide guidance on NAA flags. (Well, actually it links to a duplicate question that in turn links to that guidance.) That guidance kinda contradicts itself about whether flagging an answer like this is correct. The very first paragraph says

The "not an answer" flag is a moderator flag that users can raise to notify moderators and privileged users that a posted answer does not make an attempt to answer the question, and should be deleted.

Emphasis on "the" above is mine; at first, we're explicitly defining what the NAA flag means in relation to the question the answer was posted under. Under this definition, an answer like "The total is 42." is NAA and appropriate to flag as such when posted in response to "How do I reverse a string?" but not when posted in response to "What is 21 + 23?".
... but then the same guidance kinda softly contradicts this interpretation, later:

When reviewing "not an answer" flags, moderators aren't shown the question or comments in context without clicking further, which they probably won't do unless there's an obvious reason to look for additional context. The same applies to flags handled in the review queue for privileged users, which requires reviewers to scroll or click through to view the question or other answers.
As suggested above, subtle problems can be more effectively handled by raising an "in need of moderator intervention" flag

So under this guidance, raising a NAA flag is... probably still correct to do, just maybe not always the best option, and it might be preferable to raise a custom moderator attention flag instead.
But that's not the end! There's also guidance specific to the Stack Overflow community, documented on our Meta site, that imposes a much stricter and less woolly rule (emphasis mine; emphasis from the original removed):

You flag as NAA things posted as answers that clearly and obviously do not attempt to answer an on-topic question or the question asked. If the fact that the answer isn't an attempt to answer isn't clear and obvious, without reading the question body, then instead of an NAA flag an "in need of moderator intervention" flag should be raised

This is not equivocal like the network-wide guidance. Here we are saying: if a moderator cannot tell just by looking at the answer itself, without context that it's a non-answer, then a NAA flag is incorrect, full stop. This is not what either the flag description or the network-wide guidance on Meta Stack Exchange says; it's a policy specific to Stack Overflow that is documented only on Meta Stack Overflow.
I guess that policy is the one you should follow; as long as these flags are being handled at least in part by our mod team, it wouldn't make any sense to use them in any way other than the way our mod team asks us to use them. But people are not born magically aware of that policy and can hardly be expected to discover it prior to coming to Meta Stack Overflow over a "wrongly" declined flag, like you have done, especially given that it flatly contradicts the wording of the flag reason that specifically defines what constitutes NAA in terms of the question that the answer is posted under.
Things get worse, though! Above I've only talked about what you're supposed to do as a flag raiser. What about as a flag handler? Well, it depends! The mods enforce the policy that NAA is only valid if the post can clearly be seen to not be an attempt to answer even without looking at the question. But ordinary users sometimes get the first bite at handling NAA flags, via the Low quality answers queue. And there, per both the "Learn more" popup and the Help Center instructions, we're supposed to do something different:

This queue contains answers that the system or other users have flagged as potentially problematic.
...

Delete answers that do not address the question at all ...


(emphasis mine).

Posts entering the Low quality posts queue have been flagged as problematic by users or recognized by the system’s quality checks to be potentially low quality. This may include:
...

answers that do not attempt to answer the question asked ...

...
Basic workflow
...

Recommend deletion or Delete if you think that an answer does not address the question at all


(again, emphasis mine).
So, to sum up the five contradictory rules:

Per the flag description, you were unambiguously correct to raise your flag
Under the network-wide guidance on Meta Stack Exchange, your flag was still correct but you are advised that it's more helpful to use a custom moderator attention flag
Under the guidance specific to Stack Overflow here on MSO, your flag was unambigously incorrect
If a moderator on Stack Overflow handles such a flag, they will generally decline it in line with the policy above...
... but if an ordinary non-mod community member handles the flag, then we are supposed to delete the flagged post and thereby mark the flag as helpful, even though it was against policy for it to be raised in the first place.

This is, in my opinion, an utter mess. But it's not going to be fixed any time soon. People, including me, have been grumbling about it on Meta at least since 2018, and nothing has changed. The trouble is that fixing the system to sensibly implement Stack Overflow's site-specific policy would require:

making a change to the NAA flag description and Help Center link on Stack Overflow only to reflect our narrower definition of NAA, and
making NAA flags go only to mods, not to review queues, again on Stack Overflow only

Neither of these are changes that anyone other than staff can do.
The alternative fix is for the Stack Overflow mod team to choose to abandon the SO-specific policies we've got around NAA and embrace the definition given in the flag description - which would necessitate looking at the question a flagged answer is posted on before declining a NAA flag. But I assume they have already decided that the additional workload imposed by this would be intolerable, or else the policy we have wouldn't exist in the first place.
So we're stuck with this mess for the foreseeable future.

Re: "they have already decided that the additional workload imposed"; in some of the quoted guidance, it's mentioned that when handling NAA flags "moderators aren't shown the question or comments in context without clicking further", which is another specific item that makes the stricter interpretation less practical at SO's scale... which is extremely unfortunate. Poor tooling leads to understandable comprises in imposing rules, which in turn leads to frustrating moments for well-intentioned curators. Yay!

"but then the same guidance kinda softly contradicts this interpretation", because moderators routinely refuse to get 1 more click to have this context. They can and have the tools to get this context. Reviewers on the LQRQ get this context by default. The only solution I see to this is to explicitly show them this content. This is even told by a moderator on others sites

@CarloWood indeed, but an attempt to answer the question shouldn't be flagged as NAA, even if it's wrong. I deliberately made sure it was a wrong answer to the sum posed to make clear that even under the broader definitions of NAA, irrelevance makes an answer NAA but mere incorrectness does not.

@Braiam I dunno; I am sympathetic to the mods' desire to stop people using canned flag reasons for all but the most utterly obvious cases. A point I've made before: don't put mods who are having to churn through flags in bulk in a position where they must independently reach your conclusion reasoning from a blank slate, because that is inevitably failure-prone and more work for them; instead, spell your chain of reasoning out, even if it seems kind of obvious (to you, after spending enough time looking at the question to care to raise a flag).

@Braiam Even in this case, even if the strict SO-specific NAA policy didn't exist, it still would've been prudent to instead raise a custom flag along the lines of "NAA; the point about smooth scrolling was already in the question and thus this is purely a 'thank you' post making no attempt to add new info or answer". The problem, in my opinion, is simply that the NAA flag description says pretty unambiguously that using NAA flags in this situation is correct, and you can't expect most users to know our policy or to follow it when the flag description contradicts it.

"don't put mods who are having to churn through flags in bulk in a position where they must independently reach your conclusion reasoning from a blank slate" then mods should ask for these flags to be totally offloaded to the community, and only step in when consensus isn't achieved.

It cannot be said often enough. This conflict exists in several places. For example, the close vote description for "not about programming" says something different from the help center description of it too.

The FAQ says (emphasis mine):

If the fact that the answer isn't an attempt to answer isn't clear and obvious, without reading the question body, then instead of an NAA flag an "in need of moderator intervention" flag should be raised and you should explain the issue in more detail.

That should be it.
From a moderator's perspective, beside the "thank you" the post includes some solution. It looks like it might be answering something (also mentioned in the FAQ):

You flag as NAA things posted as answers that clearly and obviously do not attempt to answer an on-topic question [...]

If we remove the "thank you", what remains looks like it might answer an on-topic question.
So we need to inspect the question: by carefully reading it, it appears the post doesn't in fact provide an answer. The question asks "why" and not "how", and it asks "why" about something that isn't strictly about programming. Easy enough? Not quite: we just said don't flag if it requires looking at the question, didn't we?
If I were feeling generous (and a bit pedantic) and had time for it, I'd probably open the Low Quality Posts review task and hit "Looks OK" to dispute the flag. It'd be also reasonable to mark the flag helpful and not delete the post. However these are very non-standard actions in the NAA flag queue. You shouldn't expect one of these two outcomes.
We must optimize for scale.
I can't say flagging this as NAA was strictly incorrect, though considering the question can be safely closed and deleted for being both unclear and not about programming, the more appropriate course of action would've been for you to moderate the question by voting to close instead of to focus on individual answers.

My thoughts:

The question is blatantly and irredeemably off topic and does not have significant historical value. It was closed shortly before this Meta question, and it should be deleted, which would make anything to do with the answer moot.

The "thank you" is noise regardless and should be (and has been) edited out.

Considering the rest, it reads as though the post is offering a solution to the problem described.

Since it seems that the question was never edited by OP, the part at the end about disabling smooth scrolling was intended as a workaround, and not as an answer to the question. If it had been an answer to the question, then it would have been perfectly legitimate for someone to come along and convert it to an answer.

Given the above, it's perfectly understandable why the flag was declined, even if it probably shouldn't have been. If we disregard the noise, it looks like an attempt to answer "Q. How do I resolve the blank space issue?" with "A. Disable smooth scrolling", which clearly wouldn't qualify for a NAA flag.

However, it seems that "How do I resolve the blank space issue?" was not the intended question. That, in itself, doesn't validate NAA flags, either, from what I've seen. It's overall quite hard to get an NAA flag accepted.

Instead, it seems that the intended question is: "Anyone know what's going on?". Even if the overall question were on-topic, this would be unclear. Perhaps it could be interpreted as "Q. Why does the blank space appear when smooth scrolling is enabled?"; but then the only reasonable answer would be "A. It's a bug".
Which is to say, even if the question were on topic (something to do with programming rather than about a web browser which is ordinary user software), it would still be off topic. That is: a bug report for an application, even a development tool, is customer service. We'd only be interested in bugs in libraries that need to be worked around, and then a question simply trying to confirm that there's a bug would be worthless - it should be about the workaround.



Normally I would agree with you.
However, in this edge case the OP edited the solution into their question (bad) instead of posting the solution as an answer (good). The OP also, consequently, did not post the solution as an answer.
Given that this other user did post that same solution as answer (even if intending in part or in whole to be a 'thank you'), the most appropriate thing to do would be to edit the "thank you" out of the answer, edit the solution out of the question, and leave things as they are... maybe also having a mod edit the answer to make it Community Wiki.

Read the footnote, the question has not been edited.

@M-- Tomato Tomahto. We can't be sure it wasn't an edit during the grace period, but it's not really relevant to the situation whether it was an edit or included from the outset.

I disagree; that solution was in the post from the very first revision, and despite being confusingly put together, the core concern seems to me to be the final "Anyone know what's going on?", the why, not simply "how do I make it stop".

@zcoop98 In that interpretation the answer being discussed is definitely not NAA, just wrong.

I'd argue that the question is asking for the root cause of the issue, not workarounds. Even accepting your argument, I'd say the flag should've been disputed not declined. BTW, grace period is absolutely irrelevant. That "answer" is a NATO.

@TylerH I don't agree with that either; an answer which simply restates information from the question as "(thanks) this helped me" falls squarely into NAA territory, not just "wrong". It's just meta commentary on the question, that's decidedly not an answer.

@zcoop98 That's one interpretation; it's not mine. NAA flags are for things that don't offer a solution, not things that aren't the right answer; the answer being discussed was clearly the author's attempt at offering (or repeating) a solution. If I were a mod I would probably delete the answer after review, but I would not accept an NAA flag on it.

How can something be said to "offer a solution" if it fundamentally misunderstands what problem is being asked about?

Obviously if an answer was saying "Thank you! This --- insert solution from another answer --- has solved my problem" we would consider that NAA. Here, we just have this question that is asking why this issue is happening, and in the process of explaining the issue, they also presented a workaround, which understandably helped others. But all of that considered, I cannot agree that the thank you comment underneath the question and the answer that I flagged are different in nature.

@M-- Yes, but that's a different situation. This is an answer that says "thank you, this -- insert solution not from another answer -- has solved my problem". That's... an answer. Whether it's good or correct is another matter altogether, but the one thing it's absolutely not is "NAA". That's now been borne out as well by an official mod response in another answer here.

But that's not even what the question is asking about. Question asks why, that "answer" explains how.

@M-- Answers that answer another question than what was asked are also not "NAA", unfortunately. I know the description of the flag in the flag modal says that (read: "does not answer the question"), but it's not how the flag's been interpreted by mods (ever, AFAIK). I wish the modal would be updated or, preferably, mods would handle it the way the description is written. But that might start to get too far into "handling subject matter issues" territory, which mods strongly try to avoid.

We are going too deep into somewhat "philosophical" weeds. I say it's not an answer (as I explained in the question), you are saying it has a solution in it, so it is an answer. I do understand your point of view. Mine is that it is not answer, because it's a thank you comment (not because it is wrong or not answering the question, those are just side arguments). In any case, I don't wanna drag you deeper into weeds, we both have better things to do... Like merging PRs ;)
